# Relationship between rref and inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What does rref[A | AB] = [I | B] tell you if B is the inverse of A?

I understand why the two are equal, but I don't think I'm really grasping what this question wants me to think about. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: $AB$ is the identity, since $B$ is the inverse of $A$. It gives you an explicit way of calculating the inverse for a matrix, since doing elementary row operations is just multiplication by an elementary matrix.

Comment: As @K.Takeuchi said the matrix $B$ is the product elementary row operations so $rref[A|AB]$ is basically multiplying $B$ from the left $[BA|(BA)B]=[I|IB]=[I|B]$